# How to set the tagName of an Ember component based data in the model?

Tags: ember.js

I would like to set the tagName of an ember component based on data in the model like this:

```
App.TestComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: function(){return this.get('tag');}.property('tag')
});
```

This doesn't work though. The W3C specifies that you can't change the tagName of an element, so I can see why binding a variable to a static property would be problematic - just not sure how to accomplish this.

Any ideas?

Comment: How would this be used? Could you not do something in your template like: `{{test-component someVal=model.val tagName=model.tag}}`?

Comment: I tried that one also and no luck - it seems like it won't accept a model value - only seems to work with a string "p", "li" or whatever

Comment: Maybe because i'm using a relational ember-data model? hmmm...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `tagName`

```
{{test-foo tagName=item}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/molamohi/1/edit

Comment: I don't believe "Binding" is necessary - `tagName` alone should work.

Comment: you're correct, I didn't even test his statement that it wasn't working.

Comment: Thanks these examples are great - for some reason when I try it in my app it always ends up being a div: {{node.tag}} <-- this prints my tag from my data fine {{tree-node node=node tagName=node.tag}} <-- this always ends up being a div

Answer (score 3):

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vowur/3/edit shows how to set the `tagName` of a Component based on a property in a model object. Specifically:

```
{{test-component someVal=model.val tagName=model.tag}}
```

Comment: This works awesome in your code example but when I try it in mine, it's always a div - it's like it's ignoring it all together
{{node.tag}} <-- this prints my tag from my data fine
{{tree-node node=node tagName=node.tag}} <-- this always ends up being a div :(